# How to read more that 1 byte from a binary file into a value in java?

Tags: java, file, binary, byte, binaryfiles

I have a binary file with 3 different lines, each line contains non spaced prime numbers. the first one contains primes from 2 - 251 (the ones that can be fit into 1 byte), the second one starts from 257 and goes on to the biggest prime number that can be fit into 2 bytes, and so on.

Using FileImputStream I can only get the 1 line which means it only reads 1 byte at a time

my code:

```
public static void read() throws IOException {
    int tmp = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> PrimesFromFile = new ArrayList<>();
  


    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("S28006Set1.bin");
    DataInputStream In = new DataInputStream(file);
    while (( tmp  = (In.read()<< 8)) != -1) { 
        PrimesFromFile.add(tmp);

    }
     
}
```

Could anyone show me how to read more than 1 byte of info from a file into one int/ArrayList of ints?

I tried to use bitshift to get a value written on 2 bytes into 1 int, but can't seem to figure out how to do so.

Comment: "binary file" and "lines" doesn't really match. "lines" exist in text files and are separated by CR and/or LF. In Binary files those values don't exist/are interpreted differently. Generally you can use a `DataInputStream` to read a couple of commonly used basic data types in Java using `readInt` (for 4 bytes numbers), `readLong` for 8-byte numbers, ...

Comment: How do you know when to stop reading single byte numbers and start reading double byte numbers? That is: how are your "lines" delimited?

Comment: As @JoachimSauer says, that's a bad mix. You should pick one or the other, probably the text file. Then your problem will disappear

Comment: my lines are determined by the ASCII value 10 which amounts to backspace, after the value 251 there's a 10, and it goes on to the 2-byte values

Comment: That's a newline character. You should stick to (proper) text file

Comment: unfortunately i have to have it in a binary one, that's the task I was given by my Professor, At first i did it in a text file just to see how my code behaves, and everything went smoothly, but i can figure out how to do it in a binary one.

Comment: Binary files are based on offsets / record pointers and don't contain separators as such.

Comment: I mean technically you can easily define a binary format with arbitrary-length segments that are separated by some byte value, but that'd be quite pointless and annoying (since you'd need to have an escape mechanism if that value ever had to be present *inside* of such a segment).

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could define a binary format of record pointers followed by data values. The record pointer would tell you 1. whether group of primes or not 2. How many of them there are